# Subconsulta Com Resultados de Somas Diferente na Agregação

Tags: sql, query

Boa tarde pessoal,

Tenho duas consultas que trabalham perfeitamente separadas, porem preciso exibir num grid informações das duas consultas.

Preciso pegar todos as entradas de um produto e colocar numa coluna e em outra coluna as saídas...

Fiz a assim:

```
SELECT     CODIGO, DESCRICAO,
                          (SELECT     SUM(Produtos_Quant.QUANT) AS Expr1
                            FROM          Produtos_Quant INNER JOIN
                                                   produtos AS A ON Produtos_Quant.COD_PRODUTO = C.CODIGO
                            WHERE      (Produtos_Quant.TIPO <> 'REMOÇÃO')
                            GROUP BY Produtos_Quant.COD_PRODUTO) AS vEntradas,
                          (SELECT     SUM(pedidos_itens.QUANTIDADE) AS Expr1
                            FROM          pedidos_itens INNER JOIN
                                                   produtos AS B ON pedidos_itens.COD_PRODUTO = C.CODIGO INNER JOIN
                                                   pedidos ON pedidos_itens.COD_PEDIDO = pedidos.COD_PEDIDO
                            WHERE      (pedidos_itens.cancelado = 0) AND (pedidos.TIPO_PEDIDO <> 'ORÇAMENTO')
                            GROUP BY pedidos_itens.COD_PRODUTO) AS vSaidas
FROM         produtos AS C
```

Não dar erro não... porem o resultado sai errado.

Exemplo:

Fazendo a consulta separada o produto REPELEX possui 13 entradas e 12 saídas

Agora fazendo dessa forma ai o mesmo produto tem 76608 entradas e   82992 saídas

Preciso colocar em cada linha um produto com suas entradas e saídas (soma).

Onde estou errando?

Comment: coloque na pergunta a estrutura das tabelas e alguns dados de exemplo para ajudar a perceber melho o que está errado

Comment: tire os groupy by das subqueries , tendo o modelo co certeza dá para melhorar a query

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o que deseja é:

```
SELECT     CODIGO, DESCRICAO,
           (SELECT     SUM(Produtos_Quant.QUANT) AS Expr1
            FROM      Produtos_Quant
            WHERE     (Produtos_Quant.COD_PRODUTO = C.CODIGO) AND 
                      (Produtos_Quant.TIPO <> 'REMOÇÃO')
           ) AS vEntradas,
           (SELECT     SUM(pedidos_itens.QUANTIDADE) AS Expr1
            FROM      pedidos_itens INNER JOIN pedidos ON pedidos_itens.COD_PEDIDO = pedidos.COD_PEDIDO
            WHERE     (pedidos_itens.cancelado = 0) AND 
                      (pedidos.TIPO_PEDIDO <> 'ORÇAMENTO') AND 
                      (pedidos_itens.COD_PRODUTO = C.CODIGO)
           ) AS vSaidas
FROM       produtos AS C
```

correlacionar o código de produto do select mais externo com o produto em cada subselect.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, deu erro no seu codigo... acredito que seja por causa da falta do inner join da primeira subselect (entradas)... modifiquei e ficou assim:

```
SELECT     CODIGO, DESCRICAO,
                          (SELECT     SUM(Produtos_Quant.QUANT) AS Expr1
                            FROM          Produtos_Quant INNER JOIN
                                                   produtos ON Produtos_Quant.COD_PRODUTO = C.CODIGO
                            WHERE      (Produtos_Quant.COD_PRODUTO = C.CODIGO) AND (Produtos_Quant.TIPO <> 'REMOÇÃO')) AS vEntradas,
                          (SELECT     SUM(pedidos_itens.QUANTIDADE) AS Expr1
                            FROM          pedidos_itens INNER JOIN
                                                   pedidos ON pedidos_itens.COD_PEDIDO = pedidos.COD_PEDIDO
                            WHERE      (pedidos_itens.cancelado = 0) AND (pedidos.TIPO_PEDIDO <> 'ORÇAMENTO') AND (pedidos_itens.COD_PRODUTO = C.CODIGO)) AS vSaidas
FROM         produtos AS C
```

Porem, o resultado da primeira subselect ficou um valor errado (vEntradas), mais o da segunda subselect (vSaidas) deu certinho.

Onde tá o erro?

Comment: Você tem que referenciar a tabela produtos do select mais externo (C) e não fazer um inner join. O segundo subselect deu certo porque você não faz um novo inner join com a tabela produtos. Realmente tinha um erro na minha resposta acabei copiando, quando achei que estava movendo, a condição `(Produtos_Quant.COD_PRODUTO = C.CODIGO)`. Corrigido.

Comment: essa parte vai ficar assim mesmo (FROM Produtos_Quant  Produtos_Quant.COD_PRODUTO = C.CODIGO) ?